# Adding new record but time field should use current time

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cakephp 3.0.2. I would like to add a new record. A complete record `$this->request->data` would look something like this;

```
'date_taken' => [
        'month' => '01',
        'day' => '05',
        'year' => '2015',
        'hour' => '02',
        'minute' => '51'
    ],  
    'moves_per_minute' => '80',
    'person_id' => '1'
```

However, I want to HTTP Post `$this->request->data` such that it looks like this;

```
'moves_per_minute' => '80',
'person_id' => '1'
```

The `dates_taken` data should be updated automatically by using the current time.

I defined the column `dates_taken` as DATETIME type and default as CURRENT_TIME_STAMP. When I do a HTTP Post and send `$this->request->data` over leaving `date_taken` empty, the new row cannot be added.

This is how my controller code looks like;

```
$newRecord = $this->newRecords->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $newRecord = $this->newRecords->patchEntity($newRecord, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->newRecords->save($newRecord)) 
            {   
                //success
                Debugger::dump("Save success");
            } 
            else
            {
                $this->response->statusCode(400); //bad request      
                Debugger::dump("Save failure");
            }
        }
```

How should a correct controller look like?

Comment: why don't you have a field like created and modified instead ? both of the fields are updated automatically by cake itself

Comment: A field like created will be fine. Any shortcuts if a created field is used?

Comment: @ Abhishek: Thanks. I am also curious what would the solution be like if created field is not used.

Comment: @Abhishek: What should be the right default value to get current time?

Comment: You need to change your table definition to make that timestamp field into a TIMESTAMP and not a DATETIME.. [See Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the columns 'created' and 'modified' to your database table (both DATETIME), then inside the model for the table add this line:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        // Timestamp is the correct, even though the field is a datetime
    }
}
```

After you add new records, the datetime stored in the created field will be the exact time of creation and the modified field will be the last time you modify the record. Cake will do this by default every time you access this record through the entity.

More information can be found via the Timestamp documentation here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html

You could also save the current time by using the Time library and manually setting it in the entity before saving:

```
$time = Time::now();
$newRecord->date_taken = $time;

$this->newRecords->save($newRecord);
```

Again assuming the date_taken field is a datetime object in your table. I'd recommend letting the database set it for you rather than this method, though.